# SWOT Table - how to convert to an article?

Tags: tables, graphics, framed, mdframed

I need a SWOT analyse in color, and I found this one at http://www.mostlycolor.ch/2013/10/colored-blocks-in-beamer.html
:

[image]

Can someone help me by converting the beamer, so I can use it in an article? My preamble and document look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc,threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}

\newenvironment<>{problock}[1]{

\begin{actionenv}\#2
\def\insertblocktitle{#1}
\par
\mode<presentation>{
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=green!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=green!10}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red!20!black}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
}
\usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
{\par\usebeamertemplate{block end}\end{actionenv}}
\newenvironment<>{conblock}[1]{

\begin{actionenv}#2
\def\insertblocktitle{#1}
\par
\mode<presentation>{
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=red!10}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=green!20!black}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
}
\usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
{\par\usebeamertemplate{block end}\end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\section{SWOT}
\begin{frame}{SWOT Matrix}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{problock}{\textsc{strengths}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Business
\begin{itemize}
\item revenue: \$10 B
\item market share: 70\%
\end{itemize}
\item Product
\begin{itemize}
\item 32-bit color
\item written in OpenCL
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{conblock}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{conblock}{\textsc{weaknesses}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Business
\begin{itemize}
\item very expensive
\item gold plating issues
\end{itemize}
\item Product
\begin{itemize}
\item requires at least 128 cores
\item no gamut mapping
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{problock}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{problock}{\textsc{opportunities}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Business
\begin{itemize}
\item everybody wants color
\item clouds love rainbows
\end{itemize}
\item Product
\begin{itemize}
\item cameras deliver 14 bits per pixel
\item big data is pervasive
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{conblock}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{conblock}{\textsc{threats}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Business
\begin{itemize}
\item pursue low hanging fruit
\item people do not care about color quality
\end{itemize}
\item Product
\begin{itemize}
\item competitors use CIELAB
\item spectral is a new trend
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{problock}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the `<>` and `\usebeamertemplate` syntax is all beamer-specific but you are using article

Comment: The code you found will only work in the `beamer` document class, which is designed for presentations. So you can't just paste it into an `article` class document.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a way to convert it into an article?

Comment: Something like this [SWOT Matrix using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111298/1952)? You'll need to add some colors ...

Comment: Yes, and the background letter "S, W, O,T". I have tried, but it won't work.

Comment: Do you know how to do that @Ignasi

Comment: I posted an update with better code at http://www.mostlycolor.ch/2015/07/swot-matrices-in-latex.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change font, text and colors according your needs.

This code was adapted from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111298/1952) to [SWOT Matrix using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111278/swot-matrix-using-tikz/111298#111298)

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\colorlet{helpful}{lime!70}
\colorlet{harmful}{red!30}
\colorlet{internal}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{external}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{S}{helpful!50!internal}
\colorlet{W}{harmful!50!internal}
\colorlet{O}{helpful!50!external}
\colorlet{T}{harmful!50!external}

\newcommand{\texta}{Helpful\\ \tiny (to achieve the objective)\par}
\newcommand{\textb}{Harmful\\ \tiny (to achieve the objective)\par}
\newcommand{\textcn}{Internal origin\\ \tiny (product\slash company attributes)\par}
\newcommand{\textdn}{External origin\\ \tiny (environment\slash market attributes)\par}

\newcommand{\back}[1]{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    any/.style={minimum width=3cm,minimum height=3cm,%
                 text width=2.5cm,align=center,outer sep=0pt},
    header/.style={any,minimum height=1cm,fill=black!10},
    leftcol/.style={header,rotate=90},
    mycolor/.style={fill=#1, text=#1!60!black}
]

\matrix (SWOT) [matrix of nodes,nodes={any,anchor=center},%
                column sep=-\pgflinewidth,%
                row sep=-\pgflinewidth,%
                row 1/.style={nodes=header},%
                column 1/.style={nodes=leftcol},
                inner sep=0pt]
{
          &|[fill=helpful]| {\texta} & |[fill=harmful]| {\textb} \\
|[fill=internal]| {\textcn} & |[mycolor=S]| \back{S} & |[mycolor=W]| \back{W} \\
|[fill=external]| {\textdn} & |[mycolor=O]| \back{O} & |[mycolor=T]| \back{T} \\
};

\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-2-2) {strength 1\\ strength 2};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-2-3) {weakness 1\\ weakness 2};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-3-2) {opportunity 1\\ opportunity 2};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-3-3) {threat 1\\ threat 2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With a table:

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{article}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{helpful}{lime!70}
\colorlet{harmful}{red!30}
\colorlet{internal}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{external}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{S}{helpful!50!internal}
\colorlet{W}{harmful!50!internal}
\colorlet{O}{helpful!50!external}
\colorlet{T}{harmful!50!external}

\newcommand{\texta}{Helpful\par \tiny (to achieve the objective)}
\newcommand{\textb}{Harmful\par \tiny (to achieve the objective)}
\newcommand{\textcn}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\centering Internal origin\\ \tiny (product\slash company attributes)\par}}}
\newcommand{\textdn}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[b]{3cm}{\centering External origin\\ \tiny (environment\slash market attributes)\par}}}

\newcommand{\texts}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{\centering strength 1\par strength 2}}}
\newcommand{\textw}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{\centering weakness 1\par weakness 2}}}
\newcommand{\texto}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{\centering opportunity 1\par opportunity 2}}}
\newcommand{\textt}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{\centering threat 1\par threat 2}}}


\newcommand{\back}[1]{\tikz\node[overlay,text=#1!60!black,font=\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont](char) at (0,-0.1) {#1};}
\newcommand\mycolor[1]{\cellcolor{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c*{2}{C{0.2\textwidth}}}
                            &\cellcolor{helpful} \texta  & \cellcolor{harmful} \textb \\
\cellcolor{internal}\textcn & \mycolor{S}\back{S} \texts & \mycolor{W}\back{W} \textw \\
\cellcolor{external}\textdn & \mycolor{O}\back{O} \texto & \mycolor{T}\back{T} \textt
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[My previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177185/1952) needs to know size of largest box to fix the correct `minimum height`. Harish Kumar offers an alternative solution based in `tabular` which solves the problem with paragraph dimensions.

Here I offer another solution based in `tcbraster` (from `tcolorbox`). It uses 
`raster equal height=rows` option to automatically adjust (two compilations) all boxes in same row to its correct size. It also uses `watermark text` option to draw background marks. And although it has not been used in this case, `fitting` tcolorbox library could adjust inner text to fit into its corresponding rectangle.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\colorlet{helpful}{lime!70}
\colorlet{harmful}{red!30}
\colorlet{internal}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{external}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{S}{helpful!50!internal}
\colorlet{W}{harmful!50!internal}
\colorlet{O}{helpful!50!external}
\colorlet{T}{harmful!50!external}

\newcommand{\texta}{Helpful\par \tiny (to achieve the objective)}
\newcommand{\textb}{Harmful\par \tiny (to achieve the objective)}
\newcommand{\textcn}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\centering Internal origin\\ \tiny (product\slash company attributes)\par}}}
\newcommand{\textdn}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[b]{3cm}{\centering External origin\\ \tiny (environment\slash market attributes)\par}}}

\newcommand{\texts}{strength 1\par strength 2}
\newcommand{\textw}{weakness 1\par weakness 2}
\newcommand{\texto}{opportunity 1\par opportunity 2}
\newcommand{\textt}{threat 1\par threat 2}

\tcbset{swotbox/.style={size=normal, boxrule=0pt,
            colback=#1, watermark text=#1, width=.5\linewidth-5mm},
        header/.style={size=small, boxrule=0pt, width=.5\linewidth-5mm, colback=#1, valign=center, halign=center},
        firstcol/.style={header=#1, width=1cm}
        }


\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3, raster rows=3, enhanced, sharp corners, raster equal height=rows, raster force size=false, raster column skip=0pt, raster row skip = 0pt]

%Empty corner and two headers
\tcbitem[blankest, width=1cm]
\tcbitem[header = helpful]
\texta
\tcbitem[header = harmful]
\textb

%First row
\tcbitem[firstcol = internal]
\textcn
\tcbitem[swotbox = S]
\lipsum[2]
\tcbitem[swotbox = W]
\lipsum[2]

%Second row
\tcbitem[firstcol = external]
\textcn
\tcbitem[swotbox=O]
\lipsum[2]
\tcbitem[swotbox=T]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to add another format to complete this topic.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem,varwidth}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\parindent0em
\begin{document}
\section{SWOT Matrix - \emph{(Strengths, Weaknesses, Opportunities, Threats)}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    pentagon/.style={%
        shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=7.3cm, inner
        sep=-1mm, draw, fill=DarkSeaGreen!75!yellow
    }, font=\scriptsize\sffamily, thick
]
% \draw[help lines] (-16,-16) grid (16,16);
\filldraw[thin,gray,fill=gray!25] (-8,-8) rectangle (8,8);
\filldraw[thin,gray,fill=white] (-7.15,-7.15) rectangle (7.15,7.15);
\draw[thin,gray] (7.15,7.15)--(8,8) (-7.15,7.15)--(-8,8) (-7.15,-7.15)--(-8,-8)
(7.15,-7.15)--(8,-8);
% Strengths
\draw[thin,gray] (-0.025,0.025)--(-7.05,0.025)--(-0.025,7.05)--cycle;
\node[pentagon,rotate=45] at (-3.75,3.75) {
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item Technical and business expertise
\item Stable management team
\item Economies of scale
\item Financial stability
\item Acquisition capabilities
\item Domestic market orientation
\item Training programs
\item Loyalty and retention
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}
};
\draw (-2,2) node[rotate=45] {\large\textbf{Strengths}};
% Weaknesses
\draw[thin,gray] (0.025,0.025)--(7.05,0.025)--(0.025,7.05)--cycle;
\node[pentagon,rotate=-45] at (3.75,3.75) {
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item Centralized decisions
\item Marketing capabilities
\item Accounts cross-selling
\item Win on price image
\item BPO market
\item No differentiation
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}
};
\draw (2,2) node[rotate=-45] {\large\textbf{Weaknesses}};
% Opportunities
\draw[thin,gray] (-0.025,-0.025)--(-7.05,-0.025)--(-0.025,-7.05)--cycle;
\node[pentagon,rotate=135] at (-3.75,-3.75) {
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item Marketing push
\item Adding BPO capabilities
\item Pricing structure
\item Business process approach
\item Annuity engagement
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}
};
\draw (-2,-2) node[rotate=135] {\large\textbf{Opportunities}};
% Threats
\draw[thin,gray] (0.025,-0.025)--(7.05,-0.025)--(0.025,-7.05)--cycle;
\node[pentagon,rotate=-135] at (3.75,-3.75) {
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,noitemsep]
\item High-risk deals
\item Image change inability
\item Degree of automation
\item Profitability losses
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}
};
\draw (2,-2) node[rotate=-135] {\large\textbf{Threats}};
\draw(0,-7.55) node {\Large EXTERNAL};
\draw(0,7.55) node {\Large INTERNAL};
\draw(-7.55,0) node[rotate=90] {\Large POSITIVE};
\draw(7.55,0) node[rotate=270] {\Large NEGATIVE};
\draw(-0.6,0.6) node {\Huge\textbf{S}}; 
\draw(0.6,0.6) node {\Huge\textbf{W}};
\draw(-0.6,-0.6) node {\Huge\textbf{O}};
\draw(0.6,-0.6) node {\Huge\textbf{T}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]