# What would be a good way to approach making a table-like diagram with text at varying angles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, color, angle

I want to make the following diagram in LaTeX:

[image]

I started to approach making it in a table, with `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` being used for colors, but it seemed to become overly complex. What would be a good approach to making this diagram? TikZ seemed promising, but I haven't found any examples like this.

Comment: If you _started to approach making it in a table_, give us your code to help you.

Comment: You can adapt this solution with a `TiKZ` matrix to your contents: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177185/1952

Comment: @JérômeDequeker It was really just an ugly, complicated table featuring code like `\cellcolor{red!25}` for colors. I stopped when I realized how complicated it was going to get in order to avoid wasting time and asked here for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but I think a manual approach gives finer control if this is going to get more complicated. I used an overlayed rectangle based drawing such that the colors blend accordingly. Dislaimer: I'm colorblind so I randomly picked color names.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 0] in{yellow,red,blue}{
\draw[fill=\x!50,fill opacity=0.7] (0,\xi*5mm) rectangle (5,{(\xi+1)*5mm});
\draw[fill=\x!50,fill opacity=0.7] (\xi*5mm,0) rectangle ({(\xi+1)*5mm},5);
}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,anchor=south west,
       nodes={anchor=center,text=white,minimum size = 5mm,inner sep=0,
              outer sep=0,text height=1ex,text depth=0.25ex
             }
       ] at (0,0) {
e\tau&\mu\tau&\tau\tau\\
e\mu&\mu\mu&\mu\tau\\
ee&e\mu&e\tau\\
};
\node[rotate=45] at (m.center) {WEIRD STUFF!!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]