# Need help to incorporate the pictures to create a BCG matrix

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix, nicematrix

Based on what you have, you need help incorporating the images.
I would like to ask for help to create this table, the so-called BCG matrix, which I will use in my CBT:

**Likes to have the images in the frames. "Star, Question Mark, Cow and Pineapple"**

[image]

**I was thinking about using this model that is similar**
[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296733/swot-strategy-based-on-swot-matrix[][2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296733/swot-strategy-based-on-swot-matrix%5B%5D%5B2%5D)

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{article}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{helpful}{lime!70}
\colorlet{harmful}{red!30}
\colorlet{internal}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{external}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{S}{helpful!50!internal}
\colorlet{W}{harmful!50!internal}
\colorlet{O}{helpful!50!external}
\colorlet{T}{harmful!50!external}

\newcommand{\texta}{Helpful\par \tiny (to achieve the objective)}
\newcommand{\textb}{Harmful\par \tiny (to achieve the objective)}
\newcommand{\textcn}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\centering Internal origin\\ \tiny (product\slash company attributes)\par}}}
\newcommand{\textdn}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[b]{3cm}{\centering External origin\\ \tiny (environment\slash market attributes)\par}}}

\newcommand{\texts}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{\centering strength 1\par strength 2}}}
\newcommand{\textw}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{\centering weakness 1\par weakness 2}}}
\newcommand{\texto}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{\centering opportunity 1\par opportunity 2}}}
\newcommand{\textt}{\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{\centering threat 1\par threat 2}}}


\newcommand{\back}[1]{\tikz\node[overlay,text=#1!60!black,font=\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont](char) at (0,-0.1) {#1};}
\newcommand\mycolor[1]{\cellcolor{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c*{2}{C{0.2\textwidth}}}
                            &\cellcolor{helpful} \texta  & \cellcolor{harmful} \textb \\
\cellcolor{internal}\textcn & \mycolor{S}\back{S} \texts & \mycolor{W}\back{W} \textw \\
\cellcolor{external}\textdn & \mycolor{O}\back{O} \texto & \mycolor{T}\back{T} \textt
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome on the site. Take a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111278/swot-matrix-using-tikz). People are extremely helpful here as you'll see, but you need to show that you tried something first.

Comment: Thanks @JeT but likes to have the images in the frames, i don't make !

Comment: Bingo, we know where your problem is now. Given your Minimal Working Example (MWE), would you mind editing your question to explain that based on what you have, you need help to incorporate the pictures ? Don't forget to say something like "given the answer i found [the address]" to reference the code you found initially.

Answer (score 4):

A place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{231,152,0}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\arrayrulecolor{myorange}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}| l>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} | }[cell-space-limits=\tabcolsep]
 & & \Block[fill=myorange]{1-4}{\color{white}\bfseries long text}\\
 & & \Block[fill=myorange]{1-2}{\color{yellow}text} & & \Block[fill=myorange]{1-2}{\color{yellow}text}&\\
 \Block[fill=myorange]{4-1}{\rotate\color{white}\bfseries long text} & \Block[fill=myorange]{2-1}{\rotate\color{yellow} text} & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} & &  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b} & \\
 &  & & \textcolor{myorange}{\large\bfseries text:}\par\footnotesize some text that occupies multiple lines &   & \textcolor{myorange}{\large\bfseries a longer text:}\par\footnotesize some text here some text here\\
 \hline
   & \Block[fill=myorange]{2-1}{\rotate\color{yellow} text} & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c} & &  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} & \\
 &  & & some text here &   & some text here\\
 \hline
\end{NiceTabular}}

\end{document}
```