# packaging a matrix/tikzpicture into a newcommand while keeping the arguments within the style

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-matrix, arguments

I've got a SWOT matrix that works well when used in the main body of the text.

[image]

I would like to package this and use something like:

```
  \swotfigure{foo}{bar}{frut}{boo}
```

i.e. a newcommand with 4 arguments.

It uses a matrix with a tkizpicture; where the fill colours are -also- arguments.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    any/.style={
......
    mycolor/.style={fill=#1, text=#1!0!white}
```

However - when wrapping this in a new command; so it can be moved to a style - one gets into trouble with the two layers of arguments. I tried to avoid this by moving it to a preamble. But below code gives me a error (Illegal parameter in definition, can be igored actually to still get ok output).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4,final,abstracton]{book}
    
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\colorlet{helpful}{lime!70}
\colorlet{harmful}{red!30}
\colorlet{internal}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{external}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{S}{helpful!50!internal}
\colorlet{W}{harmful!50!internal}
\colorlet{O}{helpful!50!external}
\colorlet{T}{harmful!50!external}

\newcommand{\texta}{Helpful\\ \tiny (to achieve the objective)\par}
\newcommand{\textb}{Harmful\\ \tiny (to achieve the objective)\par}
\newcommand{\textcn}{Internal origin\\ \tiny (product\slash company attributes)\par}
\newcommand{\textdn}{External origin\\ \tiny (environment\slash market attributes)\par}
\newcommand{\back}[1]{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont #1}

\newcommand{\swotfigurePreamble}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    any/.style={
        minimum width=\textwidth/3, % this looks OK - but not yet found away to keep aspect ration the same as page.
        minimum height=\textwidth/3,%
        text width=\textwidth/3-0.5cm,
        align=center,outer sep=0pt},
    header/.style={any,minimum height=1cm,fill=black!10},
    leftcol/.style={header,rotate=90},
    mycolor/.style={fill=#1, text=#1!0!white}
]
\matrix (SWOT) [matrix of nodes,nodes={any,anchor=center},%
                column sep=-\pgflinewidth,%
                row sep=-\pgflinewidth,%
                row 1/.style={nodes=header},%
                column 1/.style={nodes=leftcol},
                ampersand replacement=\&,
                inner sep=0pt]{
                            \& |[fill=helpful]| {\texta} \& |[fill=harmful]| {\textb} \\
|[fill=internal]| {\textcn} \& |[mycolor=S]| \back{S}    \& |[mycolor=W]| \back{W} \\
|[fill=external]| {\textdn} \& |[mycolor=O]| \back{O}    \& |[mycolor=T]| \back{T} \\
};
}

\newcommand{\swotfigure}[4]{
\begin{center}
\swotfigurePreamble
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-2-2) {#1};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-2-3) {#2};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-3-2) {#3};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-3-3) {#4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\swotfigure{foo}{bar}{frut}{boo}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

what is the proper way to do this ?

Comment: By the way, the code for the swot matrix was taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177185/1952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single `#`, TeX expects a digit following it and assumes that it refers to a parameter. To escape this interpretation, double `#`, then it is taken as a single `#` in the next iteration of processing.

```
    mycolor/.style={fill=##1, text=##1!0!white}
```

Moreover, be careful with spurious spaces introduced by interspersed line ends, like in

```
\newcommand{\swotfigurePreamble}{
\newcommand{\swotfigure}[4]{
```

Better to remove the line end and the corresponding space by adding `%`.

```
\newcommand{\swotfigurePreamble}{%
\newcommand{\swotfigure}[4]{%
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4,final,abstracton]{book}
    
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\colorlet{helpful}{lime!70}
\colorlet{harmful}{red!30}
\colorlet{internal}{yellow!20}
\colorlet{external}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{S}{helpful!50!internal}
\colorlet{W}{harmful!50!internal}
\colorlet{O}{helpful!50!external}
\colorlet{T}{harmful!50!external}

\newcommand{\texta}{Helpful\\ \tiny (to achieve the objective)\par}
\newcommand{\textb}{Harmful\\ \tiny (to achieve the objective)\par}
\newcommand{\textcn}{Internal origin\\ \tiny (product\slash company attributes)\par}
\newcommand{\textdn}{External origin\\ \tiny (environment\slash market attributes)\par}
\newcommand{\back}[1]{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont #1}

\newcommand{\swotfigurePreamble}{% <<<<<<<
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    any/.style={
        minimum width=\textwidth/3, % this looks OK - but not yet found away to keep aspect ration the same as page.
        minimum height=\textwidth/3,%
        text width=\textwidth/3-0.5cm,
        align=center,outer sep=0pt},
    header/.style={any,minimum height=1cm,fill=black!10},
    leftcol/.style={header,rotate=90},
    mycolor/.style={fill=##1, text=##1!0!white}
]
\matrix (SWOT) [matrix of nodes,nodes={any,anchor=center},%
                column sep=-\pgflinewidth,%
                row sep=-\pgflinewidth,%
                row 1/.style={nodes=header},%
                column 1/.style={nodes=leftcol},
                ampersand replacement=\&,
                inner sep=0pt]{
                            \& |[fill=helpful]| {\texta} \& |[fill=harmful]| {\textb} \\
|[fill=internal]| {\textcn} \& |[mycolor=S]| \back{S}    \& |[mycolor=W]| \back{W} \\
|[fill=external]| {\textdn} \& |[mycolor=O]| \back{O}    \& |[mycolor=T]| \back{T} \\
};
}

\newcommand{\swotfigure}[4]{% <<<<<<
\begin{center}
\swotfigurePreamble
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-2-2) {#1};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-2-3) {#2};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-3-2) {#3};
\node[any, anchor=center] at (SWOT-3-3) {#4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\swotfigure{foo}{bar}{frut}{boo}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - that solves it perfectly and explains the why & how to properly do this as a lovely bonus. Lovely !